# How do you stub an async method using Visual studio's Fakes framework?

Tags: c#, async-await, mstest, stub, microsoft-fakes

The methods I need to stub are called e.g. like this:

```
List<DocumentInfo> documentInfosToDelete = await _documentInfoRepository.GetListByExternalIdAsync(
    partyLegalEntity, 
    externalId,
    type,
    status);
```

This works, but generates a compiler warning: 'This async method lacks 'await' operators' etc.

```
   testService.DocumentInfoRepos.GetListByExternalIdAsyncStringStringDocumentTypeDocumentStatus =
                (async (a, b, c, d) => 
            {
                GetListByExternalIdAsyncCalled = true;
                return new List<DocumentInfo>();
            });
```

I want to get rid of those warnings, as they would drown out any warnings about actual problems.

Returning new Task(...) hangs. If I understand what I have found on the WWW correctly, Task.Run(...) does something completely different from the await async pattern we are using.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `new Task(…)` hangs, because that creates an unstarted `Task`. What you can do instead is to create an already completed `Task` by calling [`Task.FromResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.7):

```
testService.DocumentInfoRepos.GetListByExternalIdAsyncStringStringDocumentTypeDocumentStatus =
        (a, b, c, d) => 
        {
            GetListByExternalIdAsyncCalled = true;
            return Task.FromResult(new List<DocumentInfo>());
        };
```

This code will behave the same as an `async` method with no `await`, but it will not produce a warning.

Answer (score 6):

@Klaus asks a great question because, for example, during testing it is great to test how the code invoking an asynchronous method behaves for success, error and cancelled. The following are defined in Task:

- Task Task.CompletedTask: property, gets a Task that has already successfully completed task
- Task Task.FromException(Exception): method, creates a Task that has completed with a specified exception.
- Task Task.FromCanceled(CancellationToken): method, creates a Task completed due to cancellation with a specified cancellation token.
- Task Task.FromResult(T): method, gets a Task that has already successfully completed task
- Task Task.FromException(Exception): method, creates a Task that has completed with a specified exception.
- Task Task.FromCanceled(CancellationToken): method, creates a Task completed due to cancellation with a specified cancellation token.

These methods and properties are shown implemented as follows:

```
public async Task JoeAsync()
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}

public async Task JimAsync()
{
    await Task.FromException(new NullReferenceException("Fake null reference"));
}

// Make sure cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested == true
public async Task JoeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.FromCanceled(cancellationToken);
}

public async Task<string> JanAsync()
{
    return await Task.FromResult("Should complete successfully");
}

public async Task<string> JedAsync()
{
    return await Task.FromException<string>(new NullReferenceException("Fake null reference"));
}

// Make sure cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested == true
public async Task<string> JanAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await Task.FromCanceled<string>(cancellationToken);
}
```

Code that tests the above methods is as follows:

```
Task task;
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancelToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
task = this.JoeAsync();
Trace.Assert(task.IsCompleted);
Trace.Assert(task.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
task = this.JoeAsync(cancelToken);
Trace.Assert(task.IsCanceled);
Trace.Assert(cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested);
task = this.JimAsync();
Trace.Assert(task.IsFaulted);

Task<string> task2;

task2 = this.JanAsync();
Trace.Assert(task2.IsCompleted);
Trace.Assert(task2.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
task2 = this.JanAsync(cancelToken);
Trace.Assert(task2.IsCanceled);
Trace.Assert(cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested);
task2 = this.JedAsync();
Trace.Assert(task2.IsFaulted);
```